# theme.xml files in GridView

Tags: android, xml

I am new to android.I want to make custom theme.I want that user can change a theme by clicking on view.I made a GridView layout and custom theme.But I dont know how to store theme.xml file to show it in GridView.I nearly searched 3 hours.Can you give me a hint how to store.Thank you.

**Edit**

```
 <style name="My_Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="page">@style/page_background</item>
    <item name="button">@style/button</item>
    <item name="text">@style/text</item>
</style>
```

I want My_Theme works when I click in GridView

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
>
```

But I dont know how to store theme.xml files to show it in Grid View

Comment: Any code you can share to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I edited my post